# no kind "Ingress" is registered for version "networking.k8s.io/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I got this error after the upgrade for my ingress from `networking.k8s.io/v1beta` to `networking.k8s.io/v1`

```
ComparisonError: failed to convert *unstructured.Unstructured to *v1beta1.Ingress: no kind "Ingress" is registered for version "networking.k8s.io/v1" in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:101"
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "{{ .Release.Name }}-service"
    nginx.org/listen-ports: "80,[::]:80,8443"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "50m"
    nginx.org/location-snippets: |
      proxy_set_header Bit-default-date-format $http_bit_default_date_format;
      proxy_set_header Bit-timezone $http_bit_timezone;
    nginx.org/proxy-pass-headers: "X-Real-IP,X-Forwarded-For,X-Forwarded-Host,X-Forwarded-Port,X-Forwarded-Proto"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "myHost"
      http: 
        paths:
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
             service: 
              name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

any hint what I am missing?

**Kubernetes** version **1.20**

**Note** this was an old project and I just update these variables without helm upgrade

Comment: probably you are at old kubernetes version? found similar threads: [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90077) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/25933).

Comment: which kubernetes version are you running?

Comment: I update my question with an answer it's 1.20

Comment: Hi, could you please tell what exactly you did in the upgrade process? What changes have you made to the `Ingress` file? Also, do I understand correctly that you are using `Helm` for this?

Comment: no I just update the variable without helm install or upgrade

Answer (score 1):

my bad I updated the ingress file without run `helm upgrade`
I revert it back to `v1beta1` for  now

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed ingress and run deployment, during the upgrade got the above error.

So I have to delete ingress manually and re-run the deployment, which worked for me

```
kubectl delete ingress ingress_name
```